# SQL injection ' and "

Tags: sql

i  been trying to solve a very "easy" ctf, Im only starting so its kind a hard for me.
its a post request and you nedd to choose a user from a list and you gehttps://ringzer0team.com/challenges/2t the user name, the group hes belong to, and a description about the user,
the post request looks like that:

```
<option value="charles">charles</option>
```

i tried to change "charles" to ""charles" OR "cedrik"" just to get both users output but the html editor auto complete the quotation marks and dosent give me output for both users.
i tried to put ' OR `'1'='1` after "sedrick so it looks like:
"sedrick' OR `'1'='1"` and it gave me all the information as well as the flag
i want to know why ' was accepted and " OR `"1"="1` dosent.
what is the diffrents between ' and ".

Comment: Single and double quote in SQL usually (but not always) mean different things.  But putting this aside for the moment, I would guess that you should look into using prepared statements with your application code (e.g. PHP).  You shouldn't be worrying about how to escape your query properly.

Comment: but why ' worked and " dosent?